# Bongo music player won't play next track in sequence

Tags: cycling, bongo

The new version of [Totem](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Videos) removed the playlist feature, so I'm looking for a simple way to choose 2 or 3 podcasts from a selection of 12 or so recently cached to a `~/Podcasts` directory.

The [bongo](https://github.com/dbrock/bongo) music player looks simpler than [EMMS](https://www.gnu.org/software/emms/), and although like EMMS it doesn't support sort-by-date in the library, it does hook into dired so I can sort most-recently-downloaded to the top in there.

Unfortunately I can't get it to play tracks continuously.

I queue a track to the playlist by pressing <kbd>e</kbd> in a dired buffer. I then press <kbd>e</kbd> with the point on another file in the dired buffer. There are now two tracks queued in the playlist buffer.

With my point on the first track I press <kbd>RET</kbd> and the track starts playing. When it ends, the audio stops. It does not start playing the next track in the playlist.

`bongo-next-action` is the default `bongo-play-next-or-stop`, but I've tried setting it to `bongo-play-next`, like so:

```
(setq-default bongo-next-action #'bongo-play-next)
```

I've tried <kbd>C-u C-c C-n</kbd> but that seems to makes no difference.

How do I make Bongo play more than one track without intervention?

I am using Emacs 24.4 on Linux, and mpg321.

Comment: I can't help you because it bugs on my emacs :( However, would you tell me the advantages of Bongo over other ones, like mpg123 that I like pretty much ? http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Media_player#Mpg123

Comment: Also, it would be useful to know how you set the new value of `bongo-next-action`.

Comment: I've added some more detail to the question, and an answer.

Answer (score 2):

When the audio is playing but also after the first track stops I can see that mpg321 is till running in the background:

```
$ ps aux | grep mpg
me       29748  6.8  0.0 2437324 6308 ?        Ssl  19:31   0:07 /usr/bin/mpg123 --skip-printing-frames 30 -R dummy
```

According to the man page `-R dummy` means run mpg123 in command mode. Looks like bongo is maybe waiting for it to exit rather than feeding it the next track to play.

Anyway, I fixed this by disabling all the backends except for `mplayer`, like so:

```
(setq-default bongo-enabled-backends '(mplayer))
```

And now bongo is playing all queued tracks in the playlist.

Answer (score 0):

When you start bongo,

Type `M-x bongo-playlist`

not `M-x bongo`

If not,

Press `C-u C-c C-n` on bongo buffer

Do it again.

Comment: I've had a hard time understanding you answer, but I think what you mean is there's both a "bongo playlist" and a "bongo library" and OP could not be using the appropriate one, is that it?

Comment: I'm sorry.

The content was modified to make it more understandable.